# Mr. Smeow's loud, annoying robot dog

Tags: inductor, inductance, speakers, induction, voltage

I bought my cat a robot dog for Xmas. He loves it! I currently have taken it apart to clean some accumulated hair out from around some of the rotating parts. It plays music that is kind of loud and shrill and annoying. If I removed the speaker from the circuit, would I need to replace it with a diode to produce a voltage drop similar to the induction of the speaker? Does the voltage drop of a speaker change with the amount of sound being produced. Do speakers produce a voltage drop when they are idle? Am I just speaking a bunch of gibberish due to my lack of knowledge on the subject? Do I need to provide more information in order for my questions to be answered?

Comment: I don't see why you would need to add a diode if you remove the speaker. That part of the circuit would just be open and it should operate like normal, minus the audio.

Comment: And if the cat likes the noise the dog makes...

Comment: I recommend to put a resistor in series to the speaker. Its loudness will reduce greatly while your cat's superiour ears will still have enough sound from the toy he loves. If you put 4 times the impedance of the speaker in series in ohms SPL wil be reduced by 14 dB. If you add 8 times the impedance you'll lose 19 dB.

Answer (score 0):

As Jay suggests usually the loadspeaker can be disconnected and the device will continue to otherwise work,  else a resistor will usually make a good replacement and you probably don't neet to be exact, use a 33 ohm resistor to replace a 32 ohm loudspeaker, or 3.9 ohm to replace 4 ohm loudspeaker etc.

Comment: I don't have access to a voltmeter right now and I can't find an image online to identify my speaker. Its 1" and says "HD" on the back with a small "19" under the"HD".